# Centrar verticalmente un span en resolucion movil

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Tengo un menú que en resolución movil el logo se pega al top de la pantalla. he probado varias cosas y no consigo centrarlo verticalmente  o ponerlo en el bottom.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom-1 navbar-fixed-top container col-xs-12" role="navigation">
<!-- El logotipo y el icono que despliega el menú se agrupan
     para mostrarlos mejor en los dispositivos móviles -->
<div class="container">

  <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Desplegar navegación</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <span id="logo">lorem lorem upse</span>
</div>

<!-- Agrupar los enlaces de navegación, los formularios y cualquier
     otro elemento que se pueda ocultar al minimizar la barra -->
<div id="main-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
 <!--  <ul id="main-nav" class="nav navbar-nav  navbar-right"> -->
  <ul  class="nav navbar-nav  navbar-right">
    <li><a  href="#about">BIOGRAFÍA</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#discography">DISCOGRAFÍA</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#videos">VIDEOS</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#contact">CONTACTO</a></li>

  </ul>

</div>
</div>

</nav>


<span id="logo">lorem lorem upse</span>
```

estoy usando **bootstrap**.
He probado con `vertical-align:middle` , `padding-top` y con `class = "align-bottom"` pero nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Creo que te faltaba algo del menú Bootstrap 3 original.**

Ahí tienes el menú con paddings. Cuando pongas el logo en `img` dentro de `.navbar-brand` si los intems del menu te quedan altos, puedes darle un `padding-top` a `ul.navbar-nav`.

Dime si te sirve o voy por otro camino. Gracias.

https://jsfiddle.net/davidfx/DTcHh/36046/

Comment: el logo no es una imagen es texto dentro de un span. en resolucion pc se ve bien pero en tablet y moviles no

Comment: Aquí lo tienes dentro de un span
https://jsfiddle.net/davidfx/DTcHh/36048/

Comment: no me funciona en movil sigue igual

Comment: el span esta en resolución movil mas arriba del menú

Comment: ya me funciona se me olvido actualizar el index.php en el servidor.

Comment: Me alegro! Si tienes algún problema más ya dices. En resumen es que no tenias el menú Bootstrap bien implementado.